# SQL multiple columns value into one column

Tags: sql

Here is my table design

```
Location                  Inventory

ID   Name                 HostName  LID1  LID2  LID3
1    AAA                   Peter      1     2     3
2    BBB                   Betty      2
3    CCC                   Charlie    1     2
```

As my expected result is like this below.

```
HostName  Name
 Peter    AAA
          BBB
          CCC

 Betty    BBB

Charlie   AAA
          BBB
```

But I run the sql statement not like this.

```
SELECT HostName,location.Name AS Department
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN location ON inventory.LID1 = location.ID
UNION
SELECT HostName,location.Name AS Department
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN location ON inventory.LID2 = location.ID
UNION
SELECT HostName,location.Name AS Department
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN location ON inventory.LID3 = location.ID
```

```
HostName  Name
Peter     AAA
Peter     BBB
Peter     CCC
Betty     BBB
Charlie   AAA
Charlie   BBB
```

Anyone can help me to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) This type of work is better done in the application than in the database.

Comment: The output you actually got is the correct table output. The output you say you desire looks like formatted output which is the responsibility of view logic that would be making the query, not the SQL query itself. It wouldn't make sense to generate a table with blank rows or blank attributes where you didn't want them repeated.

Comment: Agreed, this is a presentational issue. Let SQL do its job and just output the raw data. You can prettify it in your UI.